# Scope of a variable in functions

Tags: python

```
def swap(list1):
    print(i, j)
    temp = list1[i]
    list1[i] = list1[j]
    list1[j] = temp


list1 = [5,3,8]
i, j = 0, len(list1)-1
while i < j:
    swap(list1)
    i += 1
    j -= 1
print(list1)
```

Why am I able access the variables i, j in the function swap isn't it supposed to be out of scope?

Comment: Why would they be inaccessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple - `i` and `j` are global, so accessible from every function you define - unless you shadow them with inner definitions (e.g. `i = 'test123'` in `swap`).